# Add keywords to IPTC from same named txt files using Exiftool with batch command

Tags: metadata, keyword, txt, exiftool, iptc

I'm using AI Blip Captioning to create descriptions, keywords automatically. As you might know it creates txt files with exact same of the image. But what I want is to also add these keywords inside image IPTC Metadata. How can I achieve such thing? It does not need to be a batch file It can be a Adobe Bridge Script or something else. Basically I have millions of images in different folders and some of them are really in chaos with naming, lack of keywords and etc. My main goal is to organize things using AI Captioning tools. For example I'm using Adobe Bridge's Search. It has a feature to find image files by reading their IPTC Keywords as well.
Thank you very much,

Comment: I assume when you say "exact same of the image", you mean "exact same name of the image"?  As in "Img_001.jpg" has a corresponding "Img_001.txt"?

Comment: What is the format of the text file?  Comma separated keywords?  One keyword per line?